# Syntax error in prolog

Tags: prolog, syntax-error, swi-prolog, clpfd

I am trying to write the following formula into swi prolog but get an error,

Here is the code/query I am typing

```
[X, Y, Z] ins 0 .. 4, X #= Y + 1.
```

and here is the error I am getting

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: [X, Y, Z]
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  ins 0..4, X #= Y + 1 .
```

Could someone let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: ?- [library(clpfd)].

Comment: @CapelliC yes that was it, thanks it fixed it ]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I forgot to import the library [library(clpfd)] so basically had to use the following statement use_module(library(clpfd)). This was spotted by @CapelliC

Comment: Say rather `use_module(library(clpfd))`